# If $A_{n \times n}x=b$ has no solutions then $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

If $A$ is matrix of order $n \times n$ over an infinite field and $Ax=b$ has no solutions then $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions. 
Is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is follows from the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). If $Ax=b$ has no solution, it means that there is a vector that does not belong to the range of $A$. Hence, the dimension of the range of $A$ (i.e., the rank of $A$) is at most $n-1$. So the dimension of the kernel of $A$ (i.e., the nullity of $A$) is at least $1$. So there are infinitely many $x$ such that $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $Ax = b$ has no solutions, then $\det(A) = 0$. This is equivalent to say that $\ker(A)\neq 0$, i.e., that the system $Ax=0$ has infinity solutions (its solutions are exactly the subspace $\ker(A)$).